# How to fit 2nd order polynom to data in 2 steps using condition for rms error?

Tags: python, arrays, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I wanted to fit a polynom to data in 2 steps. First I just wanted to fit a 2nd order polynom to my data. Then I calculated the rms_error between the data and the fitpolynomial. Now I want to do a second fit using only these indexes of my data where the rms value is between 0 and 2, to avoid influence of strong spikes in the data which shouldnt contribute to my continuum fit. The variables x and data are np.arrays of same length.

```
def fit_polynom(x, a0, a1, a2):
    return a0+a1*x+a2*x**2

init_fit_param = [0, 0, 0]
fit_params, fit_covariances = scipy.curve_fit(fit_polynom, x, data, p0=init_fit_param)
rms_array = np.sqrt((data - fit_polynom(x, fit_params[0], fit_params[1], fit_params[2]))**2)

for rms in rms_array:
    if rms >= 0 and rms <= 2:
        print(rms)
```

So I can print the values of the rms_array which sattisfy my condition, now can anyone tell me how to get the index of these rms values which satisfy the condition and then do a second fit on the data. Summarize: How to get the elements of my data where the rms value is between 0 and 2 ?

Comment: Don't do it. Have a look [here](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html) on one way deal with outliers

Comment: has been done before in that way and gives good results, the physical background is the anaylsis of a galaxies spectrum, therefore I just want to fit the continuum of the spectra as good as possible , and I compensate for the fact that very strong absorption lines disturb the fit.

Comment: I'd still use a saturating loss function (just programmed it and really has some charm). Nevertheless you are looking for `numpy.argwhere` and you probably make it like `newdata = data[ numpy.argwhere( rms_array < thedesiredlimit ) ]`